# get session attribute in velocity template

Tags: spring, session, velocity

I try to get session attribute in velocity template, spring boot
but I can't get session attribute.

```
$!request.getParameter('user')
$request.getParameter('user')
#set ($user = $request.get('user'))
$user
$session.geAttribute('user')
$request.getSession().getAttribute('user')
```

I try to use theses.. but, I couldn't get right value.

How can I get session attribute in Velocity?

Comment: How did you configure velocity?

Comment: @aksappy

Application.properties 

`spring.velocity.content-type=text/html;charset=UTF-8
spring.velocity.expose-session-attributes=true
spring.velocity.expose-request-attributes=true`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the VelocityViewServlet from velocity-tools, all the 
following:

```
$session_attr  
$session.getAttribute("session_attr")
$request.getSession().getAttribute("session_attr") 
$request.session.getAttribute("session_attr")
```

should work.

You can try to check what is inside the session with the following 
fragment of code:

```
<ul> 
   #foreach($name in $session.getAttributeNames())    
      <li> $name = $session.getAttribute($name) </li> 
   #end  
</ul>
```

Comment: In filter, I can get session value
`System.out.println(req.getSession().getAttribute("user"));`

but, in velocity template, still, i can't get value.

Comment: Can you explicitly put `user` object into the Velocity Context and check whether that is getting picked up properly. I do not see a problem in the given configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better expose session attributes in mode, so you can custom `VelocityViewResolver`and setExposeSessionAttributes is true